# mat-progress-bar issue, BehaviorSubject not working

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, behaviorsubject

I can't figure out what the problem is :(

The problem is that isLoadingLogin is always set to *false*, so the mat progress bar is not displayed.

I have the following **LoginFormComponent**:

```
template: `
    {{(isLoadingLogin | async) | json }}
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="(isLoadingLogin | async)" mode="indeterminate" class="progress-bar"></mat-progress-bar>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.scss']
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isLoadingLogin: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoadingLogin = this.userService.isLoading;
  }

  login() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const email = this.form.get('email').value;
      const password = this.form.get('password').value;
      this.sessionService.login(email, password);
    }
  }
}
```

And the following services

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionService {

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe(token => {
      this.loginUser(token);
    });
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.userService.login(email, password).pipe(map(({token}: any) => this.storeToken(token)));
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private isLoadingLogin: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoading: Observable<boolean> = this.isLoadingLogin.asObservable();

  login(user, password) {
    this.isLoadingLogin.next(true);
    console.log(this.isLoadingLogin.value);
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, JSON.stringify({
      user,
      password
    }), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => this.errorHandleService.handleError('login', error)),
        finalize(() => {
          this.isLoadingLogin.next(false);
          console.log(this.isLoadingLogin.value);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

P.S. I checked that the UserService was well imported on @NgModule.

Comment: You do push `false` in `finalize`. Are you sure the HTTP POST call doesn't throw an error?

Comment: @MichaelD finalize() runs even if there's an error.

Comment: @EduardoJunior: And `false` is being pushed to it there. If there is an error, then obviously the observable holds `false`.

Comment: @7Bliz What does the console.logs that you have outputs?  The console.log inside finalize shows what?

Comment: @MichaelD yeah. But it's the right approach. That's not a problem. If he says that `isLoadingLogin is always set to false` it means that it never was `true`. At least i hope that he is explaining right hehe.

Comment: Yes it is the right approach and I want to make sure if the HTTP request goes through without any error. I wasn't questioning the usage of `finalize`.

Comment: Solved. I removed UserService from my module providers and added providedIn root. It works. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService { }
```

And remove it from my module of providers.